# How did John Quincy get informed about the availability of a heart donor?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-q

In [*John Q.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251160/), he was so ready to commit suicide by loading a bullet in the gun and he even rejected his wife's call through the walkie-talkie.

All Hospital doors are closed.

How then did John Quincy get informed about the availability of a heart donor?

Answer (score 1):

### His wife told him.

---

[**IMDB Synopsis**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251160/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> As he holds the gun to his own head a second time and prepares to end his life, **his wife is told** about a woman killed in a car crash, the one from the opening scene, who happens to have the same blood type as Michael, and has been flown to the hospital for organ recovery.
>
> **She runs to the emergency room and stops John from shooting himself**.